# Get height and width after setting maxHeight and maxWidth and auto - pure javascript

Tags: javascript, height, width

Is it posible to getGet width and height of image after setting maxHeight and maxWidth with javascript.

```
$new_image = new Image();
$new_image.src = 'xxx.jpg';
$new_image.style.maxHeight = '500px';
$new_image.style.maxWidth = '600px';
$new_image.style.height = 'auto';
$new_image.style.width = 'auto';
alert('CURRENT WIDTH AND HEIGHT IF IMAGE IS 1000 X 1000 PX');
```

I know how to get the maxheight value, but that might not be the actual size since the image is set to height and width "auto".

No jquery answers thank you! :)

Comment: the actual size 1000 could be any number bigger than max-height and max-width...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`offsetHeight` and `offsetWidth` will get you what you want, and take into account the maxWidth and maxHeight. Do keep in mind that the img object needs to be part of the DOM to have any dimensions at all. So you'll need to add it with something like `document.body.appendChild($new_image)` before offsetHeight and width will return anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dom element properties `clientHeight` and `clientWidth` for that

Comment: I need to append the image before getting the clientHeight. Thanks!